# LASTools future

Tags: discussion

As many of you may have heard Martin Isenburg, who was the founder and main developer of LASTools has passed away. LASTools is used extensively by different companies, universities and governments and currently there is no way to renew a license for LASTools. I am writing this question to assist users seeking information about the future of LASTools such as:

1. How to renew LASTools license, if possible at all?
2. Who holds the access to the LASTools source code now?
3. Will LASTools be open sourced, which Martin has mentioned many times before?

Comment: Oh god I compleytly missed that. His posts could be controversial but his work was hugely important. It's a big loss.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is being worked on.

Please follow news posted at http://rapidlasso.de/